# using multicolumn index in Jackcess to match on first column

Tags: java, indexing, jackcess

I use Jackcess 2.1.5 to read data from an Access 2003 table having a multi-column index on colA and colB. This works fine given a value for colA ***and*** colB.

Now in theory such an index can be used to get all the rows matching a value for colA ***only***. But how to do this with Jackcess? I cannot get it to work by using `newEntryIterable` or `EntryIterableBuilder`

```
Table table = access.getTable("tbl");
Index index = table.getIndex("index"); //index spanning two columns
IndexCursor cursor = CursorBuilder.createCursor(index);
for (Row row : cursor.newEntryIterable(val)) { //error: missing argument
for (Row row : cursor.newEntryIterable(val, null)) { //returns rows where colB == null
    //some code
}
```

Currently I have another index covering colA only. Is this the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a little late, but I wanted to add an update.  As of the 2.1.7 release, Jackcess now supports partial index lookups.  So, from the original question, this line will now work for finding all entries which match on the first column of the two-column index:

```
for (Row row : cursor.newEntryIterable(val)) {
```

Comment: That is good news, I updated my project to using JackCess 2.1.7, works all nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following and it worked for me. For a table named "People"

```
ID  FirstName  LastName
--  ---------  --------
 1  Gord       Thompson
 2  Jimmy      Hoffa   
 3  Jimmy      Buffett 
 4  Bob        Loblaw
```

with an index named "FirstLast" on `(FirstName, LastName)`, the code

```java
Table tbl = db.getTable("People");
IndexCursor cur = CursorBuilder.createCursor(tbl.getIndex("FirstLast"));
Map<String, String> criteria = Collections.singletonMap("FirstName", "Jimmy");
boolean found = cur.findFirstRow(criteria);
if (found) {
    boolean nextRowExists = true;
    do {
        Row r = cur.getCurrentRow();
        System.out.println(r.getString("LastName"));
        nextRowExists = cur.moveToNextRow();
    } while (nextRowExists && cur.currentRowMatches(criteria));
} else {
    System.out.println("(No matches found.)");
}
```

printed

```
Buffett
Hoffa
```

However, subsequent testing with a large file on a network share showed that the above approach is **far less efficient** than using `.newEntryIterable` and a separate index on `FirstName` only. If performance is important then you should keep that additional index just for `colA`.

Comment: This approach returns the results, but I think it does not use the index at all. So probably it comes down to either have an extra index, or live without it.
Could be an improvement to JackCess...

Comment: It does use the index to control the order in which the rows are accessed, but I believe you are correct that it doesn't use the index to help find the first matching row without scanning the table (in cursor order).

Comment: Correct, jackcess is not currently "smart" enough to do partial matching on a multi-column index using some number of initial columns.